# C# I have to Apply 10 Variables to a Label

Tags: c#

With this assignment I have to apply 10 variables into a label from a Textbox, but when I enter the variables it enters 10 of the same value from the textbox i'm really confused on this topic. Here is the code for it:

```
private void btnNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumbers.Text);
        }
        SmallestAndLargest(numbers);
    }
    private void SmallestAndLargest(int[] numbers)
    {
        Array.Sort(numbers);
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < numbers.Length; ++x)
            lblSorted.Text += String.Format("  {0} ", numbers[x]);
        lblSmallest.Text = String.Format("Smallest Number Entered: {0} ", numbers[0]);
        lblLargest.Text = String.Format("Largest Number Entered: {0} ", numbers[numbers.Length - 1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] numbers = new int[10];
int counter = 0;

private void btnNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    numbers[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumbers.Text);
    counter++;
    SmallestAndLargest(numbers);
}
private void SmallestAndLargest(int[] numbers)
{
    Array.Sort(numbers);
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < numbers.Length; ++x)
        lblSorted.Text += String.Format("  {0} ", numbers[x]);
    lblSmallest.Text = String.Format("Smallest Number Entered: {0} ", numbers[0]);
    lblLargest.Text = String.Format("Largest Number Entered: {0} ", numbers[numbers.Length - 1]);
}
```

Not the best way to do it, but it should work. Key is to declare your array outside your clickmethod since it is gone as soon as it leaves the scope of the method. Be aware though - if you exceed the 10 entries, this will throw an exception. I'll leave that as an excercise.

EDIT: The way I figured the OP has implemented this is slightly different than the answers provided so far. My interpretation was that the OP would type in an integer in a textbox and click a button, after which it will be added to the array, repeating this 10 times.

EDIT 2: Since I figured this is the way you want it, you should also change

```
for (x = 0; x < numbers.Length; ++x)
    lblSorted.Text += String.Format("  {0} ", numbers[x]);
```

to

```
lblSorted.Text = String.Empty;
for (x = 0; x < numbers.Length; ++x)           
    lblSorted.Text += String.Format("  {0} ", numbers[x]);
```

This will make sure the label text is updated, not appended.

EDIT 3: Because I am in a good mood today, here is the Form I made to test and it works as desired.

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        private void btnNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x;
            if (!Int32.TryParse(txtNumbers.Text, out x)) return;
            numbers.Add(x);
            SmallestAndLargest(numbers.ToArray());
        }
        private void SmallestAndLargest(int[] numbers)
        {
            Array.Sort(numbers);
            int x;
            lblSorted.Text = String.Empty;
            for (x = 0; x < numbers.Length; ++x)                        
                lblSorted.Text += String.Format("  {0} ", numbers[x]);
            lblSmallest.Text = String.Format("Smallest Number Entered: {0} ", numbers[0]);
            lblLargest.Text = String.Format("Largest Number Entered: {0} ", numbers[numbers.Length - 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would still give 10 variables into the lblSorted just with 9 0's and a 1 as the 10th.

Comment: As the first, actually, but if you only put in a 1 that is correct, isn't it?

Comment: But it should when you enter a variable into the textbox it enters it into the label and then you can put another number

Comment: @Arkanos yes, after sorting it should be the 10th, which is still correct. Try adding more numbers and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you assigning the same value from **txtNumbers.Text** property

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
 {
    numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumbers.Text);
 }
```

Comment: I'm still quite confused on how I can enter the variables from the textbox into the label without it entering 10 of the same values.

Comment: Every time you converting same value from textbox. Maybe just say what would you like to achieve?

Comment: What I would like to achieve is that you enter a value into the textbox and it stores it into the lblSorted and then you are able to enter another and store that one as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your enter value. So something like this:

```
private void btnNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var numbers = txtNumbers.Text.Split(' ');

    int[] convertedItems = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(numbers, int.Parse);

    SmallestAndLargest(convertedItems );
}
```

So, if you're entering values like this:

`1 2 3 5 7 9 10`

You're `numbers` array will be populated with one number each. The `Split(' ')` will split the string based where ever it finds an `space`. If they enter it a different way, you'll need to use a different delimiter for the `Split()`. You can read more about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Then in your other method, you can iterate through your array and find the smallest and largest values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter lots of values inside the texbox try:

```
string[] words = txtNumbers.Text.Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(words[i]);
        }
```

Comment: They have to be 10 Integers and to be sorted from smallest to largest.

Comment: You can add the SmallestAndLargest(numbers); after that

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this! I changed the array into an `List<Int>` and made some other little changes, but it should do what you are trying to archive!

```
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }

    private void btnNumbers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentVal = 0;
        if (Int32.TryParse(txtNumbers.Text, out currentVal))
            Numbers.Add(currentVal);
        SmallestAndLargest();
    }
    private void SmallestAndLargest()
    {

        Numbers.Sort(); //Sorts
        var max = 0;
        foreach(var x in Numbers)
        {
            lblSorted.Text += String.Format("  {0} ", x);
            max = x; //As List is sorted the current x is always the maximum value
        }            

        lblSmallest.Text = String.Format("Smallest Number Entered: {0} ", Numbers.ElementAt(0));
        lblLargest.Text = String.Format("Largest Number Entered: {0} ", max);
    }
```